# Getting Exception field - $jacocoData Exception while running Jenkins build

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber-junit

I am getting below exception while running build on Jenkins, the scenario where my build get failed is Integration-test section of my project. However all of my junit and cucumber test-cases working fine on my localmachine.

Exception which I received on Jenkins server.

```
field - $jacocoData Exception is - java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: is$jacocoData
```

Comment: I have same problem? Did you resolve? 
My jacoco maven plugin version is `0.7.9`

Comment: @fabiohbarbosa sorry for replying so late mate, yup I had closely monitor my Jenkins and my local log, there is issue with my mocking which point to the local instead of server url.

Answer (score 9):

You can see the issue：https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/168

> To collect execution data JaCoCo instruments the classes under test which adds two members to the classes: A private static field $jacocoData and a private static method $jacocoInit(). Both members are marked as synthetic.
> Please change your code to ignore synthetic members. This is a good practice anyways as also the Java compiler creates synthetic members in certain situation.

For Example refer the code below:

```
   for (Field field : fields) {
    if (!field.isSynthetic()) {
        // enter code here
    }
   }
```